# Защита от повторной отправки формы подробно

Tags: защита, html-form

Ниже идет ряд моих заблуждений по поводу пресечения повторной отправки POST,, которые я для себя записал , гуляя по разным форумам.
Они наверное выглядят смешно, поэтому я и хочу разобраться окончательно.

Вот тут habrahabr.ru/post/86280/ один человек в самом конце пишет, что можно просто создать на странице формы токен (не уникальный), а в скрипте-обработчике его уничтожить

То есть:

- Страница формы:

  ```
  $_SESSION['token'] = true;
  //html-код формы
  ```
- Скрипт-обработчик:

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] === true){
          //обрабатываем форму
          unset($_SESSION['token']);
      }
      else{
          //Выдаем ошибку о повторной отправке
      }
  }
  ```

Это решение не подходит.

Допустим если пользователь отправит форму, попадет на страницу обработчика, останется там. Токен удален , и при обновлении страницы повторная обработка данных происходить не будет. Вроде все нормально. Но.

Теперь он откроет другую вкладку, попадет на страницу с формой, тем самым создаст токен опять. Перейдя на страницу обработчика и обновив ее, он сможет отправить данные повторно, т.к. `if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] === true)` даст `true`.

Короче, метод не рабочий.

**Метод 2 - уникальный ключ для формы.**

Суть:

- создается переменная сессии или кука с уникальным значением
- к форме добавляется скрытое поле с этим уникальным значением
- в обработчике формы сверяются значения из сессии/куки и из скрытого поля
- если все совпадает, то обновляем сессионное значение/куку и выполняем необходимые процессы. Если нет - выдаем ошибку или что-нибудь по своему вкусу.

Например так:

- Страница с формой:

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['token'] = уникальное значение;
  ?>

  <form method = 'POST' action = 'script.php'>
  <input type = 'text' name = 'user_name'/>
  <input type = 'hidden' name = 'token' value = '<php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>' />
  <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit'/>
  ```
- Скрипт-обработчик:

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if($_SESSION['token'] === $_POST['token']){
          //обрабатываем форму
          $_SESSION['token'] = новое уникальное значение;
      }
      else{
          //Выдаем ошибку о повторной отправке
      }

  ?>
  ```

Гарантированная защита. Но есть проблема, и она серьезная:

Если пользователь открыл страницу формы, то у него создался уникальный ключ и приделался к форме. Он заполняет ее, может быть долго и муторно. Затем, не отправляя, по какой-то причине открывает такую же страницу в другой вкладке. Теперь у него обновился ключ сессии, и старый устарел. Он пытается отправить форму, которую заполнял на первой вкладке и получает ошибку,
т.к. токен из формы вкладки 1 не совпадает с новым.

Тут phpclub.ru/talk/threads/Защита-формы-от-повторной-отправки.83304/
fixxer предлагает (пост N 11) создать массив ключей в сессии.
проблема , как я понял, будет в том, что придется держать в сессии большое количество данных. Особенно если ключи будут длинные
Ну и если количество открытых юзером вкладок страницы с формой превысит лимит размера массива, то форма первой из вкладок все-таки не пройдет проверку.

Тут http://phpforum.su/index.php?showtopic=92222&st=0 AllesKlar, предлагает вот что:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
$_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;
header('location: form_handler.php');
exit;
}

//form_handler.php
if(empty($_SESSION['POST'])) {
exit;
}

$post_data = $_SESSION['POST'];
$_SESSION['POST'] = array();
```

Минус (наверное) в том, что на время работы обработчика сессия будет забита POST-данными, и если их размер очень большой, то сильно забита.

---

Еще один метод - тупо редирект. Безо всяких ключей и тд.
Суть:

Получаем POST данные в скрипте-обработчике, обрабатываем, а потом делаем редирект на другую страницу. Таким образом, POS-массив очищается и все, проблема решена. Но вот, что пишут тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/86280/#comment_2579959

Если это правда, то способ не очень то надежный. Его надо применять в паре с другим методом, например с уникальным ключом.

---

Пожалуй, самый лег вариант - это отправка формы через ajax.
Но это подходит не всегда. Мало ли у кого отключен JS

Answer (score 1):

Как и любая защита, эта защита должна отвечать на вопросы: "А зачем? От чего или кого?"

Если защита должна защищать от дублирования данных из-за двойного клика или переотправки, то сравнивать значения полей контента. И никак иначе. Из-за того, что я считаю, что форма не отправилась, я могу 10 раз сменить подключение и перелогиниться. Можно добавить косметический редирект после поста. Не защищает ни от чего, зато F5 не будет порождать дубли.

Если защита от атак повторов Replay Data, то делать только уникальные идентификаторы, пригодные только на один раз. Можно изобразить что-то вроде трехпакетного хендшейка из TCP.

Часто, чтобы избежать двойного клика, на форму вешается JS-обработчик, выключающий кнопку отправки. Это еще одна косметическая защита, авторов которой я проклинаю каждый раз, когда работаю с медленного соединения. К счастью, современные браузеры умеют хоткей CTRL+ENTER, что позволяет пользоваться такими сайтами - отличный пример, когда разработчикам браузеров приходится побеждать глупость авторов сайтов.

В остальном, не трогайте браузер. Пользователь к нему привык и выбрал именно его. Мир не ограничивается вашим любимым браузером и вашими любимыми настройками, позвольте пользователю пользоваться браузером так, как он того пожелает. И тем браузером, который предпочитает пользователь, даже если это Линкс. И тогда вам простят очень многое, по крайней мере вас не будут ненавидеть.

Comment: Я так и не понял, что с выключением кнопки отправки и медленным соединением не так?

Comment: Кнопку выключили, соединение висит... Висит 10, 20, 30 секунд... Очевидно, что будет висеть до посинения. Можно было бы отправить еще раз, но кнопка выключена. Остается материться, проклинать авторов и делать куклы Вуду с их фотографиями.

Comment: а если через 240 секунд таки отвиснет и отправится? У меня такое бывало, правда :D Впрочем, это в любом случае решается каким-нибудь таймаутом секунд в десять, после которого кнопку таки разблокировать, главное чтоб разработчики сайта до этого додумались)

Comment: В этом и проблема, что разработчики не додумываются. А ждать 240 секунд мне как-то лениво. И если обычную формочку еще как-то можно отправить, то с "всплывашками" на аяксе вообще полная она.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, наверное, в 21 веке, ява не отключена. Все любят всплывашки, шторки и другие визуальные эффекты.

На своем примере:

Была страница с редактированием инфы и заказчик сказал, что нужно сохранение инфы с перезагрузкой страницы. Я сделал вот так. Все данные с формы: input, select, textatea, запечатываю в массив и получаю хэш по этому массиву

```
$hash = md5(serialize(array(/*post data*/)));
```

Засовываю это в сессию, произвожу проверку

```
isset($_SESSION['hash']) && $_SESSION['hash'] == $hash
```

Если  **true** значит данные с формы не изменились, если **false** то данные либо новые, либо не изменились.

Если не понятно что говорю и интересно узнать, могу полный код сбросить.

Comment: Люди настолько любят "всплывашки", что пишут сотнями плагины вроде НоСкрипта или АдБлока, только бы всего этого не видеть. По современному интернету со включенными скриптами будет ходить только самоубийца.

Comment: В 21 веке никто не использует яву в браузерах. Зато вот яваскрипта — навалом